# Drag'n'drop file on top of quicklaunch icons doesn't work anymore

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, quicklaunch

I'm used to run files by drag'n'dropping them on top of one of the icons in quicklaunch. When I need to launch file with some app, while file is associated with another, or just use the other version of app. E.g. drag and drop png file on Paint icon or Photoshop icon, whether i need to edit it with on or another.

But now, when I drag a file of top of app in quicklaunch, icon turns to striked circle `(\)`. At the same time (what frustrates me even more), I can add a file/shortcut to qucklaunch by dragging it on the empty space (or between apps' shortcuts).

I have Windows 10 and everything was working just some time ago.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

unsurprisingly, the problem is with 7+ Taskbar Tweaker. great app, but has this issue.

Comment: The fact that it was installed is nowhere in your original question :(. That might have been useful for any potential answerer.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek there was a problem. i've found the reason. what else answer do you need? i understand the issue is very specific, while i was thinking it's general issue. that's all.